# In XCode is there a way of finding if an asset is mentioned in the workspace?

Tags: xcode

In XCode is there a way of finding if an asset is mentioned in the workspace? You know how you can right click on some text, and do "find in workspace" and it shows all the instances of that test, other than typing the assets name into a file, and then doing find in workspace, is there another way to just see where an asset is used/mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do a fast text based search with Cmd+3. This is in fact what happens when you select "find in workspace".

Comment: This kind of search doesn't find occurrence in your NIB or XIB files, to search in these kind of file you need to perform a search with the command line.